# Do I need to prepare curl in php with any special options when I receive a http response header with X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN?

Tags: php, curl, authentication, response, x-frame-options

To retrieve a successful timeclock login on a server on a separate domain, do I need to prepare curl in php with any special options when I receive a http response header with X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN?

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Send tablet keypunches to site
$post_data['user_name'] = 'public';
$post_data['password'] = '1234';
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
$cookie_jar = tempnam('/tmp','cookie');

$session =  curl_init($website);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_REFERER,$website);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $poststring );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true ); 
$output = curl_exec($session);
echo $output;
//Note: If $output contains successful message then return and wait for next staff member to login
```

Comment: hello did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I didn't receive an answer and was able to get a solution working without an answer. I apologize I don't have my code for that project available at home and my remote access was disabled because of the storm. If I am not too crazy with work when I get back after the weekend I'll see if I can guide you in any way.